# Using xolo a500 for development

Tags: android

I want to use my xolo a500 android device for development. I have already installed intel USB drivers and restarted my computer but still it is not recognized in Eclipse.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you turn on USB debugging?

Comment: Yes I did enable that

Comment: Have you connected as `Media Device` or `USB storage` mode? `Charge Only` mode won't work.
[Plus, try to install correct drivers[other] through PDANet application. You can find tons of tutorials on that though]

Comment: i having same issue with xolo a500.. have u resolved it or not?

Comment: yes for Windows7, download the drivers from Intel website (Intel Android USB Driver). But the Windows8 version of drivers is not working on Win8.

Comment: Try snappea, I used the USB storage mode, turned USB debugging on and connected the phone(Xolo Q700) via snappea....it worked like a charm...FYI, Xolo uses HTC drivers